# Getting Latest Version of Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I’m starting to learn Swift, and have tried the Swift shell. I notice that it is Apple Swift version 5.1.3 . I though it was up to 5.2 by now.

How do I get the latest version of Swift on my MacOS? Is that affected by the XCode version?

I am running MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 and XCode 11.7.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Swift comes with Xcode 11.5 which should run on Catalina. So go to the app store and download the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: I have already updated to XCode 11.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `swiftenv` to easily manage your Swift verisions. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have installed it and run `swiftenv versions` and find that it reporst `5.2.4` which looks better. However, when I run the swift shell, it still says `Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.1.3`.

Comment: Have you selected the Swift 5.2? swiftenv local 5.2.4

Comment: Just tried it. I get `.swift-version: Read-only file system`

Comment: Are you able to create any file in current directory? Try swiftenv global 5.2.4

Comment: OK, I was at the root directory for some reason. When I `cd` to `~/` the command works. However, the version I get when I just run `swift` (located in `/usr/bin/swift`) is still the old one. The tool did help me to discover that the current version is at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift`.

Answer (score 1):

https://swift.org/download/#releases

- Download Xcode 11.5 and the swift toolchain from the above link.
- Install the toolchain which is in the form of .pkg and will install the toolchain in `/Library/Developer/Toolchains`. However, if you manually build a toolchain, you can also instal it to `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains`.
- Open Xcode app menu > "Toolchains" options will appear and select the new toolchain.

For console use, run `export TOOLCHAIN=swift`. This will remain the same for *that* complier window. If you need it permanently add that line to your bash/zsh profile file and reopen Terminal.

If you built the toolchain manually, prepend the path to swift executable to the `PATH` variable.

https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift

https://github.com/apple/swift#building-swift